# error which selecting mdi child form with select case vb

Tags: vb.net, forms, enums

Okay currently I am trying to show the correct form based on choice in query click in the MDI parent, that is where I am getting a red underline. That code is this...

```
Private Sub mnLoanGpayment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnLoanGpayment.Click, mnPayGLoan.Click, mnPayGsvtgt.Click, mnSaveGpayment.Click
    '++Select case to open correct form upon selection in query.
    Dim finChild As New finChild
    Select Case sender.text
        Case mnLoanGpayment.Text : finChild.whichChild.loanamtgivenpayment
        Case mnPayGLoan.Text : finChild.whichChild.paymentgivenloanamt
        Case mnPayGsvtgt.Text : finChild.whichChild.paymentgivensavetgt
        Case mnSaveGpayment.Text : finChild.whichChild.savingsgivenpayment
    End Select
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    finChild.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    finChild.Show()
End Sub
```

Currently I have in my finChild class for choices in the forms as this at the moment...

```
Public Class finChild
Private minamt As Decimal = 1000
Private maxamt As Decimal = 2000000
Private minpmt As Decimal = 1
Private maxpmt As Decimal = 10000

Public whichChild As Which

Public Enum Which
    loanamtgivenpayment
    savingsgivenpayment
    paymentgivenloanamt
    paymentgivensavetgt
End Enum

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim finutl As New FinClass
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    '++Reset form to default values and perform default math
    cbMonths.Text = 36
    cbRate.Text = "6.00" & "%"
    txtAmount.Text = 10000
End Sub
```

End Class

So in the MDI form when they are under the query item on the menu bar and they choose which form they want to appear, it would go through the switch case which would then go through the enum in `finChild` and from there, the form is built in `finChild` which switch cases to modify forms. but in the MDI parent when I try

```
        Case mnLoanGpayment.Text : finChild.whichChild.loanamtgivenpayment
        Case mnPayGLoan.Text : finChild.whichChild.paymentgivenloanamt
        Case mnPayGsvtgt.Text : finChild.whichChild.paymentgivensavetgt
        Case mnSaveGpayment.Text : finChild.whichChild.savingsgivenpayment
```

all of these statements are underlined in red with message `Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated. Expression is not a method.`

Comment: Shouldn't it be finChild.Which.loanamtgivenpayment?

Comment: says `Expression is not a method`

Comment: you need to use a method ie assign it to a variable eg x = finChild.Which.loanamtgivenpayment

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict - sender is Object which does not have a Text property

Comment: Where is this option strict?